# SSLSocket problem using BufferedWriter

Tags: java, android

Im having problem sending command when using BufferedWriter

Here is example

```
    SSLSocketFactory f = context.getSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("198.168.0.10", 8888);
    c.setSoTimeout(20000);
    c.setUseClientMode(true);
    c.startHandshake();

        BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(
           new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
        Thread.sleep(500);
        w.write("username");
        w.flush();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        w.write("password");
        w.flush();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        w.write("command");
        w.flush();
        Thread.sleep(50);
```

Problem is without Thread.sleep it doesnt work, if i lower number than 50 problems begin. Any idea how to fix it, or mabe use another writer?

Comment: What does the server code look like? (I'm thinking the server software is brittle if it requires input data to come in multiple packets.) Should the client be waiting for a specific response from the server rather than sleeping or sending all the content at once?

Comment: its a hardware, thats why i can not see code. They just expose commands, but no tutorial or real API. What is interesting, in .Net code i dont have thread.sleep. It works perfect. Thats why i thought maybe i dont use proper classes in Java.

Comment: does the `OutputStreamWriter` perform any buffering itself? Or will it take a `flush()` command from the `BufferedWriter` and flush to the SSL stream too?

Comment: Not that i know of. without flush() its not working, thats why by calling it, it send commands.

Comment: override handshakecompletelistener, and pass it SSLSocket.addHandshakeCompletedListener and onHandshakecompelte start your reading and writing.